# Cloning On Bitbucket Using SSH protocol

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh-keys, deploying

Am trying to clone a private repository from bitbucket to my local machine. And am having a error below
[image: Error image]
I created a key from my windows  local machine in cmd using 
`ssh-key gen - t rsa -c "ussr@domain.dom"`
And imported the keys to bitbucket as below. 
[image: preview on bitbucket]

How can I resolve this issue guys? , thank you.

Comment: Try using git@bitbucket.org:... instead of git://bitbucket.org/...

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: open c:/users/YOURNAME/.ssh/ id_rsa.pub and copy paste that text there

Comment: It is actually ``git@bitbucket.org:``  not ``git://bitbucket.org:`` The issue was I was using a slash after ``git@bitbucket.org``  instead of colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the key to the local ssh-agent, as described at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html.

Comment: I everything again and I tried to create a key again. when open cmd and run
`cd %userprofile%/.ssh` then
`dir id_*`
To check whether I have created the key. It shows

 `Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9267-BB95

 Directory of C:\Users\TEAMLEADER\.ssh

File Not Found`

Does it mean my machine doesn't create the key?

Comment: @novapack, the key may have been created in the directory from where you run `ssh-keygen`, it depends on your environment (that is, which SSH-implementation is used) and which options you used. If not given any ouputfile OpenSSH_7.8p1 will prompt for an outputfile, using $HOME/.ssh as default destination directory, if the value does not start with a '/' will the path be a relative path from the current directory.

Comment: I think I the error I hard in the comment above. I deleted the .ssh folder and created a new key without entering the **key file in which to save the key**. Added the key to the ssh-agent as you mentioned above. Now when I run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` I get `You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.

This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:

LinearcDevs/linearwebsite: Linearc -- TEAMLEADER@LINEARC-PC1` Doesn't this mean that bitbucket can now connect securely?

Comment: @novapack, it means that Bitbucket recognise your key (the command you run is just for testing that) and that you have read access to the repositories mentioned in the response through ssh/git protocol (e.g. `git clone git@bitbucket.....`).

Comment: But still, it doesn't work it brings the same error (first image in the question) if I use git://bit..... .when I use git@bit...i get **' does not exist**  and then **Could not read from remote repository.** when I use ssh://

Comment: @novapack, I recommend that you verify that correct url is used when cloning the repositort from Bitbucket (see https://youtu.be/0M3LilUsX9Y) and that it correspond with the response you got when you verified the deploy key.

Comment: thanks, team. it worked fine I was using `git@bitbucket.org/` instead of `git@bitbucket.org:` you the best.